# How do I get text below Icon button with font awesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I'm attempting to create a button with Bootstrap and Font Awesome, the catch is I want to have descriptive text below the stacked icon itself.   All of the examples are left and right is anyone putting text below?

I've begun playing with it at url below, but any jump start suggestions are appreciated.

http://www.bootply.com/86861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't really any solution within the BS, Font awesome approach, so I went ahead and wrapped several parts with divs and did the styling that way.

```
<div class="ecGlobalNavStudentPanelBtnWrapper">
    <div class="ecGlobalNavStudentPanelBtn"> <span class="icon-stack floatButton"> <a href="http://library.edgewood.edu/"><i class="icon-check-empty icon-stack-base"></i> <i class="icon-archive"></i> </a></span> </div>
    <div class="ecGlobalNavStudentPanelBtnTxt hidden-xs">
        <p><a href="http://library.edgewood.edu/">library</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can make this solution work for one item, but how do you get multiple items lined up this way?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you try `<i class="icon-book">book</i>` ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks Gray. I'll try your suggestion